# Shortest route from addresses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I have a list of string addresses and I'm drawing them on a google map with geocoding. What's the best way to find shortest route between them?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: I will also throw out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: I am aware of that,but is there a service that can calculate it for me?